# Invisible style template in Microsoft Word

Tags: templates, ms-word

Years ago, I created a special style template for an auto-numbered list in Microsoft Word (2003) that looks something like this:

```
Fig. 1
Fig. 2
...
```

I need to delete this style template because it keeps appearing in various places and Word mistakenly applies it even to normal bullet lists.

The style is stored in normal.dot. However, it is not shown under "Styles".

I have already deleted all styles from normal.dot that are deletable. All remaining styles refuse to be deleted.

What other options are there for finding and deleting the style template in question?
Hex-editing normal.dot?

For certain reasons, I cannot create a new normal.dot at the moment, but have to continue working with the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

### First look for the list gallery file. Move or rename it with Word closed.

C:\Users%Username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Word\ListGal.dat

This may be hidden if you do not have the view option to see hidden and system files.

**You can rename your Normal.dot(m) file**

If you are still using Word 2003, it is Normal.dot. Any later version it is Normal.dotm. This must be done with Word closed. Here is [my writing on how to find the Normal template](https://addbalance.com/word/normaltemplate.htm#Find). I do not know if that will help. If you rename this template, Word creates a new one from its default settings.

Comment: From the below link I suppose that ListGal.dat is only applicable and existing from Word 2007 onwards. It is not present on my system. I also have already deleted the List Gallery Presets key in
the registry, but without success.
https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.word.application.errors/c/Uaz2Ph9Zrzo/m/et42QJL77k8J

Comment: I confess ignorance as to that. When asking questions about Word it is important to specify the version involved, especially 97-2003 vs 2007-present. "Normal.dot" should have given me a clue.